# linker error cannot find symbol name in library

Tags: linker, g++

```
g++ (GCC) 4.7.2 
3.7.6-201.fc18.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Feb 4 15:54:08 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Fedora release 18 (Spherical Cow)
```

Hello,

I am compiling and having a problem trying to link a program.

The linker error is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: point.o: undefined reference to symbol '_Znwj@@GLIBCXX_3.4'
/usr/bin/ld: note: '_Znwj@@GLIBCXX_3.4' is defined in DSO /lib/libstdc++.so.6 so try adding it to the linker command line
/lib/libstdc++.so.6: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This object file is `point.o` is trying to call a function that doesn't exist in libstdc++.

When I try and check if the symbol name does exist using readelf I can't find it.

```
readelf --all libstdc++.so.6.0.17 | grep _Znwj@@GLIBCXX_3.4
```

Is this because the point.o is looking for a symbol in a older libstdc++ that could have been removed in a later version?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Could you show your compilation line?

Comment: Also, what function do you attempt to call which doesnt's exist in libstdc++? Do you know for sure it doesn't exist there?

Comment: I have the same problem on code that used to work, when now porting to a different linux machine, that is compiling both C and C++ source into the same executable.  I suspect it has something to do with the way the namespace is munged.

Answer (score 13):

In my case I was using gcc not g++.  It used to work in '12, but a later build on a different machine in '14 choked.  The gnu compiler has indeed changed.  The answer in my case was to add

```
  -lstdc++
```

onto the end of the linking line, as the error messages suggest.  HTH.