# undefined reference to symbol '_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4' building OpenCV on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I'm on Ubuntu Trusty and I'm building the following code with this command.  I'm new to clang and I could use help debugging these errors. The cpp and hpp files these C bindings are from compile fine. I copied the headers from those files into the below file I have listed here, w.cpp

```
    clang -std=c++11 w.cpp -o w `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Here are the errors:

```
        /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/w-2a90f4.o: undefined reference to
        symbol '_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4'
        //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: error adding 
         symbols: DSO missing from command line
        clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 
          (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is the contents of w.cpp. I'm trying to benchmark code using
clang.

```
        #include <opencv2/c/mat.hpp>
        #include <opencv2/c/opencv_generated.hpp>
        using namespace cv;
        using namespace std;
        using namespace flann;
        using namespace cvflann;


        void cv_delete(char* self) {
             delete self;
        }


        Mat* cv_create_Mat() {
            return new Mat();
        }


        BFMatcher* cv_create_BFMatcher(int normType, bool crossCheck) {
            return new BFMatcher(normType, crossCheck);
        }




        int main () {

         for( int a = 1; a < 20; a++)
           {
              Mat a =  &cv_create_Mat(); 

              cv_delete(a);
           }

        }
```

Comment: `c++filt` says that  `_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev` is the decorated/mangled name for `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()`.  The `@@GLIBCXX_3.4` is clearly some library versioning tag, but I don't know the mechanism for how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Try adding: `-stdlib=libc++`

Comment: @Brett Hale  Thanks for commenting on my post:)...That did help...now I'm getting  /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvdef.h:343:12: fatal error: 'cmath' file not found #  include <cmath>

Comment: in case someone gets the same error with `gcc` instead of `clang` then make sure you use `g++`

Comment: See this if you are using g++ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888626/linker-error-cannot-find-symbol-name-in-library

Comment: If you are using clang on linux you may have noticed that /usr/bin/clang++ is a link to /usr/bin/clang and just used 'clang' instead of c++. @Ciprian's answer for gcc fixes the problem for clang as well. I suppose clang is parsing its invocation call and noting the ++.

Answer (score 24):

I had the same error using gcc instead of g++, I believe you must use clang++

```
clang++ -std=c++11 w.cpp -o w `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

While compiling C++ files, its better to use

```cpp
g++ client.cpp -Wall -lstdc++ -o client
```

Comment: For GCC you should use `g++`!